# Why is there unnecessary whitespace while plotting figures with pandas, matplotlib and seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Whenever I plot figures using matplotlib or seaborn, there is always some whitespace remaining at the sides of the plot and the top and bottom of the plot. The (x_0,y_0) is not in the bottom left corner, x_0 is offset a little bit to the right and y_0 is offset a little bit upwards for some reason? I will demonstrate a quick example below with the 'ggplot' style so it is clear what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,5,11)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,1,1])
ax.plot(x,x**2)
```

[image]

How do I get (0,0) to the bottom left corner and how do I get rid of the unnecessary space where y > 25, x >5?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "whitespace" is caused by the [plot *margins*](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html?highlight=margins#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins). A better way to get rid of them without changing the axes limits explicitly is to set 0-margins

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,5,11)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,1,1])
ax.margins(x=0,y=0)
ax.plot(x,x**2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To not have borders you can use `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`:

```
ax.set_xlim([0, 5])
ax.set_ylim([0, 25])
```

[image]

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,5,11)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,1,1])
ax.plot(x,x**2)
ax.set_xlim([0, 5])
ax.set_ylim([0, 25])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok, I see how this works in this specific example, but I get the same kind of problem when I create figures like boxplots using seaborn, how would I fix it in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
x = np.linspace(0,5,11)
plt.xlim((0,5))
plt.ylim((0,25))
plt.plot(x,x**2);
```

[image]