# Whitespace around figures in seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I've been using seaborn for some data visualisation, but for some reason the axes and spacing seem a little off. This also happens when I use matplotlib and pandas for data visualisation. I will show an example to illustrate my point:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.style.use('ggplot')
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips') # a dataset 
sns.distplot(tips['total_bill']) # 'total_bill' is a column in the dataset
```

[image]

As you can see, there is a start of a new grid above 0.06 on the y axis and also above 60 on the x axis.

This happens with every plot I do, whether it be a distplot, countplot, boxplot, and I'm not sure why it's happening? I've been learning this through an online course and whenever the instructor runs the code, the figures don't have this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787270/1356000), you can control this behavior using `plt.margins()`

Compare this code to yours:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.margins(x=0,y=0)
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips') # a dataset 
sns.distplot(tips['total_bill']) # 'total_bill' is a column in the dataset
```

[image]

If you would like to change this property globally, you can change [your rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html). The relevant keys are `axes.xmargin` and `axes.ymargin`

Comment: Ok, thank you! Is there any way to get it to go up to the 0.06 on the y axis and 60 on the x axis, but no extra? And how would I do this in general?

Comment: You could set `plt.ylim((0, 0.06))`

Comment: @JohanC Ok, I see, but is there a way to do this sort of thing globally? To have it as default?

Comment: It's hard to give a strong definition of the kind of behaviour you're asking.